# Laravel json request all

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5

Request JSON :

```
{ "name":"xxxx", "login":"", "uid": ""}
```

Response : 
How to $request->login; // xxxx
help please thank you.

Comment: unclear what you are saying ?

Comment: $request->json()->get('name') return empty value

Comment: how you got this output ? `{ "name":"xxxx", "login":"", "uid": ""}` ? share that code ?

Answer (score 0):

use json_decode [link here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

this will help you converting json to array or object